# Regex to skip all folders except one

Tags: regex, google-app-engine

I have the following entry to a file that ignores certain files and directories when I deploy my app:

```
skip_files:
- ^default/node_modules$
- ^cron$
- ^default/static/app$
- ^\.git$
- ^default/(.*/)?#.*#$
- ^default/(.*/)?.*~$
- ^default/(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
- ^vendor/(.*/)?.*\.dat$
- ^keys/!privateKeys.json$
- ^default/(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
- ^default/(.*/)?\..*$
```

Also I have the following directories:

> vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Google/Service/Acceleratedmobilepageurl
> vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Google/Service/AdExchangeBuyer
>
> vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Google/Service/AdSense

I want to have a single rule in the skip files section that ignores the first two ones, but still deployes the Adsense folder.

The reason for this is that Google/Service/* includes a lot of folders but actually I need only two of them to be uploaded. It would make more sense to have a single rule instead of 100 individual ignore rules.

Comment: I read about the negative lookahead but I do not know how to use it. I am a n00b when it comes to regex.

Comment: Did Avinash's solution below work for you? If yes, please consider upvoting/accepting.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use negative lookahead.

```
^Google/Service/(?!AdExchangeBuyer\b|AdSense\b)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/9qPQcU/2)

Comment: this worked for me, including Angular in the node modules folder:
- ^node_modules/(?!@angular)